# Apex charts skipping some data points with identical values

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

The data is a sensor timeseries data (96 timestamps with 15 minute difference) with many adjacent identical values.

```
data = [
{x: 1606387737082, y: 0.03}
{x: 1606386837082, y: 0.03}
{x: 1606385937082, y: 0.03}
{x: 1606385037082, y: 0.03}
{x: 1606384137082, y: 0.03}
{x: 1606383237082, y: 0.03}
{x: 1606382337082, y: 0.03}
{x: 1606381437082, y: 0.03}
{x: 1606380537082, y: 0.02}
{x: 1606379637082, y: 0.02}
{x: 1606378737082, y: 0.02}
{x: 1606377837082, y: 0.02}
{x: 1606376937082, y: 0.02}
{x: 1606376037082, y: 0.02}
{x: 1606375137082, y: 0.02}
...
]
```

What I've noticed is, three or more same valued data points are being shown as only two values picking the first and last of the same-valued adjacent data points.

```
this.chartOptions = {
  ...
  xaxis: {
    type: "datetime"
  }
}
```

Trying [axisTicks](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/#axisTicks) settings makes no difference, as it's only for the numeric data.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283055/set-a-certain-interval-for-x-axis-ticks-in-apexcharts) has some similarity to mine, however I'm not trying to change the resolution of displayed datetime ticks; but a straightforward `{"x":<timestamp>, "y":<value>}` data points display on the chart, without skipping the adjacent identical values that are 15-minute apart.

Comment: Your series is sorted in descending order (the timestamps values are reversed in your code). Can you try sorting the data into ascending order and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: @junedchhipa, thank you for the reply. The data series (timestamps) is now in ascending order, yet the issue persists as before. Out of 96 values, only around 35 data points are being plotted.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a Codepen?

Comment: It's working as expected, it has always been!! The widget embedding the chart was too small to notice all the data points. Verified by putting `markers` in the chart. Here's the [reproduced demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xctkmo). Thank you, (sorry for the inattentive testing from my part).